# Network Protocol Conversion -- Prior Art Request for US 2005/0220286 A1 (Verizon)

Tags: prior-art-request, internet, network, protocol, us20050220286

https://www.google.com/patents/US20050220286

The independent claim is drawn primarily to **protocol conversion of the data link layer and the application layer of a communication without conversion of intermediate layer(s)** (network layer, transport layer). There are some additional limitations, but the heart of the matter seems to be this element.

There are numerous pieces of prior art that disclose protocol conversion at the data link layer. There are also numerous pieces of prior art that disclose protocol conversion at the application layer. There are even numerous pieces of prior art that disclose protocol conversion at both the data link layer and at the application layer. I am, however, unable to find a reference that explicitly or incontrovertibly documents conversion at the data link layer and at the application layer **without** any conversion of intermediate layers.

The date to beat is March 28, 2005. Your assistance is appreciated.

Entirety of independent claim 1:

> 1. An integrated communications device including hardware components, the device comprising:
>      a first processor configured to control a first hardware component function;
>      a second processor configured to run an abstraction interface and a client application, the client application providing a user interface;
>      wherein the abstraction interface is adapted to make a direct conversion between protocols used by the first processor and protocols used by the client application, by converting data link layer protocols and application layer protocols without converting at least one of network layer protocols and transport lay protocols, to permit control of the first hardware component function via the client application, and
>      wherein the client application is adapted to output data using at least one of session layer protocols, presentation layer protocols, or application layer protocols.